# How to subsample a 2 dimensional python array

Tags: numpy, slice

I have a N x M sized numpy array named my_array.

I want to down sample the array and eliminate rows 1,3,5,7... and columns 1,3,5,7...

I can eliminate the rows using my_array[::2]

I can eliminate the columns in a for loop.
Is there a way to eliminate the columns using slicing?

Answer (score 1):

Using slicing this can be done with the following syntax:

```
my_array[::2 , ::2]
```